# How do I find out where a URL redirects to in Node JS (without the request module)

Tags: node.js, redirect, request, http-redirect

Sadly, most of the Stack Overflow answers/questions regarding this use the request library, [which is deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142). I have a URL, for example `http://bitly.com/3eZyxM1` (which redirects to `https://google.com`, which then redirects to `https://www.google.com`). Given the first URL (the bitly one), how can I figure out the first place it redirects to (not the final location, the first place it goes to, which is `https://google.com`. I'm fine with using third-party `npm` libraries, so long as they aren't deprecated. Ideally, it should work in Node.js 16 or newer.

Comment: The page you link to includes a link to a list of alternatives, did you try using any of those?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the hint, turns out I didn't look through that list very closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [got library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got). I installed it with `npm install got`.

I was able to use it by doing this. It imports the library, gets (or `got`s) the URL, and it gets everything it redirects to, and then uses [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to only get the URL itself, and not the other information.

```js
import got from 'got'

got('http://bitly.com/3eZyxM1').then((res) => {
    console.log(res.redirectUrls.map(url => url.href))
})
```

That printed out the redirect path (by defualt, it gives a bunch of into about the URL, so I use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to just get the URL itself. That prints out this:

```js
[ 'https://google.com/', 'https://www.google.com/' ]
```

Then you can just get the first element of the array:

```js
got('http://bitly.com/3eZyxM1').then((res) => {
    console.log(res.redirectUrls.maps(url => url.href)[0])
})
```

Which gives this:

```
https://google.com/
```